# Google Calendar Api insert event return error "Invalid start time"

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

I try run api for insert event , and somethime i got error "Invalid start time" :
My parametrs is:

```
{
 description: "desription text"
 end: {dateTime: "2019-10-01T13:30:00+02:00"}
 location: "location text"
 start: {dateTime: "2019-10-01T11:00:00+02:00"}
 summary: "summary text"
}
```

I try insert event for 2019-10-01 11:00-13:30.
How can I solve my problem, what  is wrong in my datetimes? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used the following request in "Try this API" window for insert event [1] and worked perfectly:

```
{
  "description": "desription text",
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2019-10-01T13:30:00+05:00"
  },
  "location": "location text",
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2019-10-01T11:00:00+05:00"
  },
  "summary": "summary text"
}
```

It could be that you're missing the double quotes for the attributes or the commas between them.

[1] https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert